# Executing java program by command line argument

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am working on stanford code nlp package to get sentiment result.

In execution I need to give the text file name as a input.

`java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar -Xmx600m edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse -file input.txt`

input.txt contains some text.

Can some one tell me here how can I pass string text directly rather giving a file name `input.txt`?

Comment: Write another program that reads the input.txt file, creates a commandline with the contents of the file and passes it to Runtime exec().

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify your main program in such a way that it reads from arguments.

eg:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    // here args[] will contain you input strings
//check null for args
    //args[0] --> -annotators 
    //args[1] --> values of -annotators 
    //args[2] --> /file or -inputs 
    //args[3] to args[length] --> you input text
for(int i=3;i<args.length;i++){
    System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```

And then your command line appears as

> java -cp
>   stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar
>   -Xmx600m edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse  -inputs this is my input text

Note: you would need to provide validations

Answer (score 0):

Warning:  I haven't tried this ...

If you run StanfordCoreNLP with neither `-file` or `-filelist` arguments, it runs as a "shell", reading input from stdin until it sees a `q`.  So you might be able to do this:

```
$ ( echo "text to be parsed" ; echo q ) | \
  java -cp ... edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP ...
```

But IMO it is cleaner if you send the text to a file and then use the application as it was designed to be used; e.g.

```
$ echo "text to be parsed" > /tmp/input
$ java -cp ... edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP ... -file /tmp/input
```